# plot own function wolfram mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I found a problem with function plot. I have tree arrays of points and want draw a function using theese arrays. Here I add my code. It's gave me only result of function but didn't draw a graphic of my function

```
x = {-2, -0.5, 1, 2.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5}
k = {-10.5, -7.5, -4.5, -1.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5}
m = {6, 7.5, 4.5, -3, -11, -15.5, -20.5, -26}
y[x] == k*x + m
Plot[{y[x]}, {x, -5, 6}]
```

Please, help me solve this problem
Thanks, Viktoriya

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you read up on [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html).

```
x = {-2, -0.5, 1, 2.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5};
k = {-10.5, -7.5, -4.5, -1.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5};
m = {6, 7.5, 4.5, -3, -11, -15.5, -20.5, -26};

y[x_] := k*x + m

Plot[y[x], {x, -5, 6}]
```

Comment: but I have a mistake in program
SetDelayed::write: Tag List in {27.,11.25,0.,-6.75,-9.,-8.75,-8.,-6.75}[x_] is Protected. >>

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just want this:

```
 x = {-2, -0.5, 1, 2.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5};
 k = {-10.5, -7.5, -4.5, -1.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5};
 m = {6, 7.5, 4.5, -3, -11, -15.5, -20.5, -26};
 y = k x + m;
 ListPlot[ Transpose[{x, y}]  , Joined -> True]
```

[image]